# how to validate ckeditor with jquery validate in rails?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, ckeditor

my view code:

```
<%= f.cktext_area :description, class: 'form-control', id: 'description', rows: 8, required: true %>
<script>
  CKEDITOR.replace('description');
</script>
```

this will generate an html code like this:

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="description" rows="8" required="required" name="product[description]">
</textarea><script>
//<![CDATA[
(function() { if (typeof CKEDITOR != 'undefined') { if (CKEDITOR.instances['description'] == undefined) { CKEDITOR.replace('description'); } } else { setTimeout(arguments.callee, 50); } })();
//]]>
</script>
```

and here is my script to validate above code:

```
$(function(){
  $("#product_form").validate({
ignore: [],
    rules: {
      description: {
        required: function(){
          CKEDITOR.instances.description.updateElement();
        }
      }
    }
  });
})
```

I've been following this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rohanppatil/BmZ93/8/) and customized with my need, but nothing happen. Can anybody help me? thanks

Comment: Create a jsFiddle to demonstrate the issue.  FYI, the `function()` used for your `required` rule makes no sense.  `required` is only set to `true` or `false`.  Either the field is required or it isn't.  What are you trying to do?  Have you simply tried setting `required: true`?

Comment: Also, JavaScript does not care about your server-side framework.  All that matters is the HTML rendered in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems below...

```
rules: {
    description: {
        required: function(){
            CKEDITOR.instances.description.updateElement();
        }
    }
}
```

1. You are only supposed to use the `name` of the field, **not** the `id` within the `rules` option.  In this case, `product[description]`.
2. Having a `function()` as the parameter of the `required` rule makes no sense in this context.  The field is either `required` or it isn't, so this rule can only be `true` or `false`.

Try this...

```
rules: {
    "product[description]": { // <-- name of the field
        required: true        // <-- this field is required
    }
}
```